# Function invariant under composition w order automorphism

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

A. Given a totally (linearly) ordered set $A$ and a not constant function $f: A \rightarrow B$, are there any known conditions which guarantee there is no order automorphism  $g :A \rightarrow A$, $ g\neq Id $ such that $f=f \circ g$?

B. Does it make any difference to the question $A$ above if the set $A$ is the Real numbers?

C. Does it make any difference to the question $A$ above if the set $A$ is a closed interval of the real numbers?

D. Does it make any difference to the question $A$ above if the set $A$ is equipped with the corresponding order topology, $B$ is a topological space and $f$ is continuous?

E. Is such a condition that $ f $ does not take at least two different values at least countably infinite times each?

Comment: I guess you want no other automorphism except the identity?

Comment: Then there's the notable condition that $g^{-1}=g$ is necessary.

Comment: Yes,  you are right,  yours is a better way to frame the question (I am looking for conditions that guarantee that there is no other automorphism than the identity)